# unable to restore mysql database, getting ERROR 1153 (08S01)

Tags: mysql

trying to restore pressflow database and getting this error, I even tried it with `--max_allowed_packet`, still getting same error:

```
[root@6shdbm01 tmp]# mysql --max_allowed_packet=1024M pressflow < pressflow.sql 
ERROR 1153 (08S01) at line 786: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
[root@6shdbm01 tmp]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max_allowed_packet` variable must be set on both the client and the server. If the server's value is lower than the client's value, this error occurs.

You will need to set `max_allowed_packet` in the `[mysqld]` section of `/etc/my.cnf` to complete the operation.

For more information, [see the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html).

Comment: how can I see inside of mysql what this variable equals too now?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';`